# Crop/Cut a Diagonal Area in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know this question might seem a bit too silly but I've been trying to do this for an hour. [image: Image I'm trying to crop/cut]

As you can see in the image, I attempted to cut the area shown in red lines (which are diagonal) and fill it with white so only the bottom part with the green lines are seen. I:

> 1: Tried the crop tool and making a preset (but the area was rectangular and there was no option for diagonal or straight areas.
>
> 2: Tried shaping the eraser to a diagonal line which resulted in imperfect cuts.
>
> 3:Tried to paint the whole place but failed.

So is there a way for me to perfectly crop the image so that the only visible part is the bottom?

Comment: Images can only be square, you need to mask or clip instead. Use pen tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would draw shapes and use them as a mask for the Layer:

First, draw the shapes:
[image: First, draw the shapes]

Combine them and Rasterize them, then select them(CTRL+CLick on the Layer):
[image]

Create the Layer Mask:

[image]

Invert the Layer Mask(If the Panel isn't the double-click the Layer Mask.)

[image]

And you're done :)
(If you want you can right-click the Mask and click "Apply Layer Mask" to bake the Mask in)

[image]

Comment: Or you could just right click on the select tool thing (rectangle made of dotted line) and choose polygonal select.

Comment: you don't explain how to cut which icon to click i got lost with the eraser because you didn't show how to do that